# Button navigationLink to other fileView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to make a button to go on other ViewFile but when I try, The button or text don't go to my other file, how I can solve it ?

I have try

```
Button("Accéder à l'actualité"){
                    NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), label: {
                        EmptyView()
                    })
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

But I have error

I want to connect : img1 to img2
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsNha.png) to [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWp0S.png)

I want when I click on The button "Accéder à l'actualité" I switch on The other View/file

This is my code : StartView file :

```
import SwiftUI

struct StartView: View {
    
    @State private var willMoveToNextScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "newspaper")
                    .padding(.bottom, 2.0)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("NEWS APP")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                Button("Accéder à l'actualité"){
                    NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), label: {
                        EmptyView()
                    })
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
            .padding()
    }
}

struct StartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StartView()
    }
}
```

and HomeView file

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(AllNews.list, id: \.id){
                AllNews in ArticleItemView(AllNews: AllNews)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .overlay(
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: AllNewsDescriptionView(AllNews: AllNews), label: {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        ).opacity(0)
                    )
            }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Articles")
        }
    }
}

struct ArticleItemView: View {
    let AllNews: AllNews
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.white
                .cornerRadius(8)
            HStack{
                image
                info
            }.padding()
        }.shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
    }
}

private extension ArticleItemView {
    var image : some View {
        Image(AllNews.image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
    }
    var info : some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text(AllNews.name)
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .lineLimit(1)
            Text(AllNews.description)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .lineLimit(2)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

How I can solve it ?

Comment: Your button has a `NavigationLink` as the `action` parameter: `NavigationLink` is a view, not an action. Try putting the `Button` inside the `NavigationLink`, in the place of `EmptyView()`.

Comment: A NavigationLink is a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationLink` only works inside a `NavigationStack` or the deprecated `NavigationView`.
It is like a button, so in `StartView` use it like this without the `Button`:

```
 NavigationStack {
     // ...
     NavigationLink("Accéder à l'actualité", destination: HomeView())
     // ...
 }
```

There is no need for another `NavigationView` in `HomeView`.

EDIT-1:

Here is my test code, to show that my answer works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View{
        StartView()
    }
}

struct StartView: View {
    @State private var willMoveToNextScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <--- here
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "newspaper")
                    .padding(.bottom, 2.0)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("NEWS APP")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.ultraLight)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                // --- here, NO Button
                NavigationLink("Accéder à l'actualité", destination: HomeView())
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    .tint(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    // for testing
    @State var allnews = ["news-1","news-2","news-3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        // ---> NO need for NavigationView here
        List(allnews, id: \.self){ news in
            Text(news)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                .overlay(
                    // for testing
                    NavigationLink("", destination: Text("destination \(news)")).opacity(0)
                )
        }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Articles")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already try this, but when I click on "Accéder à l'actualité" nothing happens. Why ? I don't know and in HomeView, their is NavigationView for other page

Comment: updated my answer with the code I used to show it works. Let me know if this code does not work for you.